# Python 2.7 Rock Paper Scissors Not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

hi i am practicing python and doing rps game.
This is the code:

```
class Choices:
    rock = "Rock"
    paper = 'Paper'
    scissors = 'Scissors'

def rps_game():

    # Getting the name of the player.
    name = raw_input("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Game!\n Enter your name:")

    # The Players Choice.
    while True:

        player_choice = raw_input("\n1-Rock\n2-Paper\n3-Scissors\n{} choose a number:".format(name))
        int(player_choice)

        if player_choice == 1:
            player_choice = Choices.rock
        if player_choice == 2:
            player_choice = Choices.paper
        if player_choice == 3:
            player_choice = Choices.scissors


    # Getting the cpu choice.
        cpu_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
        if cpu_choice == 1:
            cpu_choice = Choices.rock
        if cpu_choice == 2:
            cpu_choice = Choices.paper
        if cpu_choice == 3:
            cpu_choice = Choices.scissors


        if player_choice == cpu_choice:
            print"\n Its a Tie!/n{} you!".format(name)

        if player_choice == Choices.paper and cpu_choice == Choices.rock:
            print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)

        if player_choice == Choices.scissors and cpu_choice == Choices.paper:
            print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)

        if player_choice == Choices.rock and cpu_choice == Choices.scissors:
            print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)

        else:
            print"\n Too Bad You Lost!".format(name)



        print "\nCPU Choice: {}\n Your Choice: {}".format(cpu_choice, player_choice)

        play_again = raw_input("Want to Play Again? y/n")
        if play_again == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            break
```

I defined only when the player is winning or its a tie and for the else i did else statement. But and a big But it will always will output always the lose output for some reason and when its print the choices for the CPU it prints a string the describes the choice(Paper Scissors ...) But for the players choice it prints the number
So Id be happy to get Your opinion what am i doing wrong and ALSO Id be happy to get some tips what are your thoughts and tips to get my code more efficient and professional

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a string, so `player_choice == 1` will never be true.

Comment: corrected spelling mistakes, updated title

Comment: You forgot about `elif`

Answer (score 1):

```
player_choice = raw_input("\n1-Rock\n2-Paper\n3-Scissors\n{} choose a number:".format(name))
int(player_choice)
```

This code doesn't work. `player_choice` is set as a string from `raw_input` but `int(player_choice)` doesn't do anything. It creates an integer and then sends it into the void. Instead, you need to reassign it to `player_choice` like so:

```
player_choice = int(player_choice)
```

Comment: thnx but this is not the main problem , the main problem is that even if the player loses or its a tie the program run the winner print or the tie print and also the lose print

Answer (score 1):

```
if playerChoice == 1 and compChoice == 3:
    print("You Win - Rock crushes Scissors.")
if playerChoice == 2 and compChoice == 1:
    print("You Win - Paper covers Rock.")
if playerChoice == 3 and compChoice == 2:
    print("You Win - Scissors cut Paper.")

if compChoice == 1 and playerChoice == 3:
    print("You Lose - Rock crushes Scissors.")
if compChoice == 2 and playerChoice == 1:
    print("You Lose - Paper covers Rock.")
if compChoice == 3 and playerChoice == 2:
    print("You Lose - Scissors cut Paper.")
```

Comment: Personally I would use this, defines  both outcomes to both user and computer.

Answer (score 1):

In your existing code. The else only applies to the final if statement. So if the player choice is not `Rock` and the cpu choice is not `Scissors` then the else is printed.

To resolve this use elif to make a chain of if statements. Then the else will apply only if none of the if conditions are met e.g.

```
if player_choice == cpu_choice:
    print"\n Its a Tie!/n{} you!".format(name)
elif player_choice == Choices.paper and cpu_choice == Choices.rock:
    print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)
elif player_choice == Choices.scissors and cpu_choice == Choices.paper:
    print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)
elif player_choice == Choices.rock and cpu_choice == Choices.scissors:
    print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)
else:
    print"\n Too Bad You Lost!".format(name)
```

You also need to convert the return value from `raw_input` to an int. Otherwise its a string and will never be equal to any of the integer values representing the choices. So use `int(raw_input())` instead.

I see you tried to do this by using `int(player_choice)`. The int constructor does not work 'in place'. i.e. it doesnt convert the variable itself to an int. It returns an integer value leaving `player_choice` as a string. You can see when we wrap `input` in the call to `int` we are capturing the return value and so `player_choice` is then an int (assuming your input was convertible to int).

Here's a that will work on python 2 and python 3.

```
import random
from sys import version_info

if version_info.major == 2:
    try:
        input = raw_input
    except NameError:
        pass

class Choices:
    rock = "Rock"
    paper = 'Paper'
    scissors = 'Scissors'

def rps_game():

    # Getting the name of the player.
    name = input("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Game!\n Enter your name:")

    # The Players Choice.
    while True:

        player_choice = int(input("\n1-Rock\n2-Paper\n3-Scissors\n{} choose a number:".format(name)))

        if player_choice == 1:
            player_choice = Choices.rock
        elif player_choice == 2:
            player_choice = Choices.paper
        elif player_choice == 3:
            player_choice = Choices.scissors


    # Getting the cpu choice.
        cpu_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
        if cpu_choice == 1:
            cpu_choice = Choices.rock
        elif cpu_choice == 2:
            cpu_choice = Choices.paper
        elif cpu_choice == 3:
            cpu_choice = Choices.scissors


        if player_choice == cpu_choice:
            print("\n Its a Tie!/n{} you!".format(name))

        elif player_choice == Choices.paper and cpu_choice == Choices.rock:
            print("\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name))

        elif player_choice == Choices.scissors and cpu_choice == Choices.paper:
            print("\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name))

        elif player_choice == Choices.rock and cpu_choice == Choices.scissors:
            print("\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name))

        else:
            print("\n Too Bad You Lost!".format(name))



        print ("\nCPU Choice: {}\n Your Choice: {}".format(cpu_choice, player_choice))

        play_again = input("Want to Play Again? y/n")
        if play_again != 'y':
            break

rps_game()
```

Also here's an attempt to implement it in less code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
from sys import version_info

if version_info.major == 2:    
    input = raw_input

choices = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')

winlogic = {
    'Rock': 'Scissors',
    'Paper': 'Rock',
    'Scissors': 'Paper'
}

def calcwinner(choice1, choice2):
    if choice1 == choice2: return 0
    return 1 if winlogic[choice1] == choice2 else -1

name = input("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Game!\nEnter your name: ")

while True:

    index = int(input("1-Rock\n2-Paper\n3-Scissors\n{} choose a number: ".format(name)))
    try:
        player_choice = choices[index - 1]
    except IndexError:
        print('please make a valid choice')
        continue

    cpu_choice = random.choice(choices)
    winner = calcwinner(player_choice, cpu_choice)

    print('You chose {} and computer chose {}. '.format(player_choice, cpu_choice), end='')

    if winner == 0:
        print('Tie')
    elif winner < 0:
        print('Cpu won')
    else:
        print('You won!')

    play_again = input("Want to Play Again? y/n: ")
    if play_again not in ('y', 'Y', 'yes'):
        break
```